# How to store an array in hdf5 file which is too big to load in memory?

Tags: python, memory, numpy, hdf5

Is there any way to store an array in an hdf5 file, which is too big to load in memory?

if I do something like this

```
f = h5py.File('test.hdf5','w')
f['mydata'] = np.zeros(2**32)
```

I get a memory error.

Comment: Take a look at [hyperslabs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#chunked-storage). It is possible, but you should write in 'chunks', and make the hdf5 file chunkable.

Comment: http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#chunked-storage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#chunked-storage), you can use `create_dataset` to create a chunked array stored in the hdf5. Example:

```
>>> import h5py
>>> f = h5py.File('test.h5', 'w')
>>> arr = f.create_dataset('mydata', (2**32,), chunks=True)
>>> arr
<HDF5 dataset "mydata": shape (4294967296,), type "<f4">
```

Slicing the `HDF5 dataset` returns Numpy-arrays.

```
>>> arr[:10]
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
>>> type(arr[:10])
numpy.array
```

You can set values as for a Numpy-array.

```
>>> arr[3:5] = 3
>>> arr[:6]
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  3.,  0.], dtype=float32)
```

I don't know if this is the most efficient way, but you can iterate over the whole array in chunks. And for instance setting it to random values:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> for i in range(0, arr.size, arr.chunks[0]):
        arr[i: i+arr.chunks[0]] = np.random.randn(arr.chunks[0])
>>> arr[:5]
array([ 0.62833798,  0.03631227,  2.00691652, -0.16631022,  0.07727782], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: What if dataset size is not known beforehand? Can it be done in append mode?

Comment: @mrgloom Maybe this suits your needs? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25656175/3635816