# Add constant value to an array which is stored in an hdf5 file

Tags: python, file, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I want to add a constant value to an array. The array is stored in an hdf5 file.

```
f = h5py.File(fileName) 
f['numbers'] = f['numbers'] + 5
```

gives me an error that `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Dataset' and 'int'`

how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f['numbers'][:]+=5` works.

`f['numbers'] + 5` does not work because the Dataset object does not have methods like `__add__`.  So the Python interpreter gives you the `unsupported` error.

Adding the `[:]` gives an `ndarray`, with the full set of `numpy` methods.

Doesn't the documentation talk about loading slices of the data into memory?

```
`f['numbers'][:10] += 5
```

might work as way to change a portion. The addition is still being done in memory.

See earlier questions like
[How to store an array in hdf5 file which is too big to load in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209293/how-to-store-an-array-in-hdf5-file-which-is-too-big-to-store-in-memory?rq=1)

Another option is to look at the compiled `h5` code.  There probably are Fortran or C based scripts which will make changes to the data like this.  You could easily call those from Python.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [the actual `numpy.add` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html):

```
ds = f['numbers']
ds[:] = np.add(ds, 5)
```

(Though I *do* like your syntax better. Maybe that's worth suggesting to the h5py people.)