# Resizing and storing dataset in .h5 format using h5py in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, h5py

I am trying to resize dataset and store new values using `h5py` package in python. My dataset size keeps increasing at every time instance, and I would like to append the `.h5` file using the `resize` function. However, I run into errors using my approach. The variable `dset` is an array of datasets.

```
import os
import h5py
import numpy as np

path = './out.h5'
os.remove(path)

def create_h5py(path):
    with h5py.File(path, "a") as hf:
        grp = hf.create_group('left')
        dset = []
        dset.append(grp.create_dataset('voltage', (10**4,3), maxshape=(None,3), dtype='f', chunks=(10**4,3)))
        dset.append(grp.create_dataset('current', (10**4,3), maxshape=(None,3), dtype='f', chunks=(10**4,3)))
        return dset

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dset = create_h5py(path)
    for i in range(3):

        if i == 0:
            dset[0][:] = np.random.random(dset[0].shape) 
            dset[1][:] = np.random.random(dset[1].shape)
        else:
            dset[0].resize(dset[0].shape[0]+10**4, axis=0)
            dset[0][-10**4:] = np.random.random((10**4,3))
            dset[1].resize(dset[1].shape[0]+10**4, axis=0)
            dset[1][-10**4:] = np.random.random((10**4,3))
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to [tel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425458/tel) I was able to solve this. Replace `with h5py.File(path, "a") as hf:` with `hf = h5py.File(path, "a")`.

Comment: The main problem is that `dset` appears as `[<Closed HDF5 dataset>, <Closed HDF5 dataset>]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tel provided an elegant solution to the problem. I outlined a simpler approach in my comments below his answer. It is simpler for a beginner to code (and understand). Basically, it there a few minor changes to @Maxtron's original code. Modifications are:

- move `with h5py.File(path, "a") as hf:` to `__main__` routine
- pass `hf` in `create_h5py(hf)`
- I also added a test before `os.remove()` to avoid errors if the h5 file
  doesn't exist

My suggested modifications below:

```
import h5py, os
import numpy as np

path = './out.h5'
# test existence of H5 file before deleting
if  os.path.isfile(path):
    os.remove(path)

def create_h5py(hf):
    grp = hf.create_group('left')
    dset = []
    dset.append(grp.create_dataset('voltage', (10**4,3), maxshape=(None,3), dtype='f', chunks=(10**4,3)))
    dset.append(grp.create_dataset('current', (10**4,3), maxshape=(None,3), dtype='f', chunks=(10**4,3)))
    return dset

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with h5py.File(path, "a") as hf:
        dset = create_h5py(hf)
        for i in range(3):

            if i == 0:
                dset[0][:] = np.random.random(dset[0].shape) 
                dset[1][:] = np.random.random(dset[1].shape)
            else:
                dset[0].resize(dset[0].shape[0]+10**4, axis=0)
                dset[0][-10**4:] = np.random.random((10**4,3))
                dset[1].resize(dset[1].shape[0]+10**4, axis=0)
                dset[1][-10**4:] = np.random.random((10**4,3))
```

Answer (score 3):

## The problem

Not sure about the rest of your code, but you can't use the context manager pattern (ie `with h5py.File(foo) as bar:`) within a function that returns a dataset. As you point out in the comment under your question, this means that by the time you try to access the dataset the actual HDF5 file will have already closed. The dataset objects in `h5py` are like live views into the file, so they require the file remain open in order to use them. Thus, you're getting errors.

## A solution

It's a good idea to always interact with files within a managed context (ie within a `with` clause). If your code throws an error, the context manager will (almost always) ensure that the file is closed. This helps avoid any potential losses of data resulting from a crash.

In your case, you can have your cake (encapsulate your dataset creation routines in a separate function) and eat it too (interact with the HDF5 file within a managed context) by writing your own context manager to look after the file for you.

It's actually pretty simple to code. Any Python object that implements the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods is a valid context manager. Here's a complete working version:

```
import os
import h5py
import numpy as np

path = './out.h5'
try:
    os.remove(path)
except OSError: 
    pass

class H5PYManager:
    def __init__(self, path, method='a'):
        self.hf = h5py.File(path, method)

    def __enter__(self):
        # when you call `with H5PYManager(foo) as bar`, the return of this method will be assigned to `bar`
        return self.create_datasets()

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        # this method gets called when you exit the `with` clause, including when an error is raised
        self.hf.close()    

    def create_datasets(self):
        grp = self.hf.create_group('left')
        return [grp.create_dataset('voltage', (10**4,3), maxshape=(None,3), dtype='f', chunks=(10**4,3)),
                grp.create_dataset('current', (10**4,3), maxshape=(None,3), dtype='f', chunks=(10**4,3))]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with H5PYManager(path) as dset:
        for i in range(3):
            if i == 0:
                dset[0][:] = np.random.random(dset[0].shape) 
                dset[1][:] = np.random.random(dset[1].shape)
            else:
                dset[0].resize(dset[0].shape[0]+10**4, axis=0)
                dset[0][-10**4:] = np.random.random((10**4,3))
                dset[1].resize(dset[1].shape[0]+10**4, axis=0)
                dset[1][-10**4:] = np.random.random((10**4,3))
```

Comment: My question is an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655588/incremental-writes-to-hdf5-with-h5py). Here, the author uses `with h5py.File` to `open` the file. However, it is not used in a function.

Comment: Many thanks for providing for valuable feedback. I think your method of using `class` to interact with the `dset` object is a very clean and robust implementation.

Comment: You can also move `with h5py.File(path, "a") as hf:` to `__main__`, then pass `hf` in `create_h5py(hf)`. You get the context manager and a simpler `def`. What is the advantage of writing a custom context manager? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your suggestion would be a simpler pattern for a beginner to implement than what I presented above (I wanted to show what was going on inside of the context manager, but I may have gotten a bit carried away). You should add an answer based on that idea to this thread.